# Direct upload of Video to Vimeo

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload directly to [Vimeo](https://www.vimeo.com/) from my computer in a [Wordpress](https://www.wordpress.com/) site using `$lib->upload($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  false);` but it keeps failing. Plus it can't upload large files above 1MB,target is to allow users to upload upto 100MB in a single upload

Comment: Not sure about how you do this on a wordpress.com site but is your php.ini set up correctly to upload 100MB files?

Comment: yea, i extended the `max_upload_size` to 200MB

Comment: When you say "It keeps failing" can you provide additional information about why it's failing? Additionally can you provide a link to the code behind the upload method?

Comment: I have `$video = $lib->upload($video_file,  true);`  to handle the upload function. The response comes in the form of `videos/1234567` on success but the video is **untitled**. When the upload is unsuccessful i get  a `null` response.  I may have the implementation wrong or this method is not the correct method for uploading a video and still keep the title @Dashron

Comment: Which library are you using? The function should never return null and the filename must be added via a secondary request. Specifically $lib->request($video_uri, ['name' => $title], 'PATCH');. If you are finding that some requests are null, you should post an issue to the code's issue tracker!

Comment: please clarify on the `$lib->request($video_uri, ['name' => $title], 'PATCH');`
does the `$video_uri` in this came mean /videos/1234567?
@Dashron

Comment: Glad to hear it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the conversation happened in the comments above, but I'm adding an answer here anyway.

The video was being uploaded successfully, the problem was that the video was returning as "untitled".

To edit a video you need to perform the API call `$lib->request($video_uri, ['name' => $title], 'PATCH');`, and ensure your token has the edit scope.

Comment: You seem to know a lot about the Vimeo API.  My project I am trying to add the vimeo api so that user's can upload their videos to my websites account.  This is in a custom Plugin that I wrote.  The problem is the the loading of the library causes the site to crash.  Do you have any examples?

Comment: Hey Debbie, I used to work for Vimeo, but no longer do. Your best bet now is to reach out to their support.

Comment: Have done that.  Hopefully, they can help me figure it out.  The library crashes on any attempt to do this: 

 $Vimeolib           = new Vimeo($VimeoClientId, $VimeoClientSecret, $VimeoAccessToken);